# If $T\geq 0$ then $|\langle x,STx\rangle|\leq\|S\|\langle x,Tx\rangle$

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, analysis, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

I am trying to prove that on a complex Hilbert space, if $T\geq 0$ and $S$ is any bounded linear operator, then $T\geq 0$ then $|\langle x,STx\rangle|\leq\|S\||\langle x,Tx\rangle|$.

Comment: Which norm are you considering for $S$?

Comment: @Semiclassical The operator norm, $\|S\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Sx\|$.

Comment: Since the space is complex, shouldn't you be comparing the absolute values of the inner products?

Answer (score 3):

This is not true. Let $\theta>0$ be sufficiently small,
$$
T=\pmatrix{\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta&\cos\theta}
\quad\text{and}\quad
S=\pmatrix{\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\ 0&0}.
$$
Then $T>0$ and $\|S\|=1$, but $|\langle e_1,STe_1\rangle|=1>\cos\theta=\|S\|\langle e_1,Te_1\rangle$.